# Finding/filtering calendar by Graph API's ICalUid in Exchange Web Services Managed API

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

In Graph API client there is a Filter extension method that can be used when building the request, usable also for ICalUid filtering. How can I retrieve an appointment in EWS Managed API just by its ICalUid?

**[Update #1 - 11.13]**

As mentioning Graph API might have suggested, I need this method to work with Office 365, and not necessarily on older Exchange versions. That would be "a nice to have" feature of the solution.
What I really need is an ID that is unique to the meeting but same in all calendars, and works with orphan and exception occurrences as well. It looks, that ICalUid satisfies this criterion in Graph API, but not with EWS, as EWS returns the same ICalUid for each occurrence.

**[Update #2 - 11.13]**

It looks like the property I need is [PidLidGlobalObjectId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815676.aspx). I have found several posts, how to retrieve it as ExtendedProperty, and I am able to retrieve it when using `CalendarFolder.FindAppointments` and `ExchangeService.BindToItems`. But I am unable to use this property as a filter. I know that I have to convert this binary property to Base64.

```
var s = Convert.ToBase64String(searchval);
var sf = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(PidLidGlobalObjectId, s);
var fi = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(MailboxToAccess));
var cf = await CalendarFolder.Bind(service, fi);
var res = await cf.FindItems(sf, new ItemView(1)); // yields empty
```

`FindItems` without SearchFilter returns all Single and RecurringMaster items. Thus this is the equivalent of Graph API's `events` collection. But I need to filter the CalendarView as this property makes sense only where series occurrences and exceptions are individual objects. In Graph API, `calendarview` is a separate collection that is filterable with OData queries.

*Is there any way to achieve the same: to use a `SearcFilter` but applied on the CalendarView?*

(Note: I am accessing foreign calendars without impersonation, just by using permissions.)

Thank you!

Comment: No you can't use a SearchFilter with a CalendarView, what you can do is just limit the properties returned in the results set of calendar query and filter the results at the client, then Bind to those items you want more information on.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of....